# Image Displays over Content

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add content on an image however I'm not sure where to place the code. When I place it above everything, it takes priority and none of my code shows. However when I place the image in the body CSS, it displays but I have problems trying to place my next line of code at the end of the image and not on the image below my last line of code which in this case is the Shop Now. I'm pretty sure I have placed the IMG code somewhere wrong. I appreciate anyone's help.

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="Image">
<img src="C:\Users\Gabriel\Downloads\Green-blur.jpg"/>
<ul id="nav">
    <li id="brand"><a href="#">MINIMAL</a></li>
    <li id="navm"><a href="#">Men</a></li>
    <li id="navm"><a href="#">Women</a></li>
    <li id="navm"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<h1>Simplicity is Minimal</h1>

<div id="home">
<a href="#" id="homeb">Shop Now</a>
</div>

</div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
<!--Content from code shows-->
body {
background-image: url();
background-size: 100% 130%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
font-family: "PT Sans", sans-serif;

}
<!--IMAGE TAKES PRIORITY-->
img {
height: 1000px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Gabriel. Welcome. You should toss that code into a jsFiddle or something. So, your goal is to have the text and links 'on top' of the image?

Comment: Yes. I want the image as the background and the content in my html code on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
body {
font-family: "PT Sans", sans-serif;
}

.image {
  background: url("https://www.blogcdn.com/www.joystiq.com/media/2011/06/respawngameblurryimage530pxheaderimg.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

li a{
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
<ul id="nav">
    <li id="brand"><a href="#">MINIMAL</a></li>
    <li id="navm"><a href="#">Men</a></li>
    <li id="navm"><a href="#">Women</a></li>
    <li id="navm"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<h1>Simplicity is Minimal</h1>

<div id="home">
<a href="#" id="homeb">Shop Now</a>
</div>

</div>
```

Note: Removed the image in your HTML and added it to your CSS.

Hope it helped

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is that you want to put content over the image.
You can achieve this by using background image as you have done but for background image you have to provide the correct path of the image.

In your code
background-image: url('path of your image'):
background-size: contain;

Remove image tag from html.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, I think you're wanting that image to be the background on `body`, so you can move the `src` of your `img` into the `background-url()` property on `body`. And if you want the background to span the entire height of the browser window, add `min-height: 100vh;` to `body`.

```css
body {
  background-image: url(http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_EqZzf-l7OCg/TNmdtcyGBZI/AAAAAAAAAD8/KD5Y23c24go/s1600/homer-simpson-1280x1024.jpg); /* put your "C:\Users\Gabriel\Downloads\Green-blur.jpg" image here */
  background-size: 100% 130%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-family: "PT Sans", sans-serif;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul id="nav">
    <li id="brand"><a href="#">MINIMAL</a></li>
    <li id="navm"><a href="#">Men</a></li>
    <li id="navm"><a href="#">Women</a></li>
    <li id="navm"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>

  <h1>Simplicity is Minimal</h1>

  <div id="home">
    <a href="#" id="homeb">Shop Now</a>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to think about images and content on top of them. One would be to add a background-image to the element the content resides in. In other cases you'll want to use the image to maintain ratio and then position the content 'on top' with absolute positioning.

markup

```
<header>
  <div class="stuff">Stuff here... example with background image</div>
</header>

<!-- OR -->

<div class="thing">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/1600x900" alt="">
  <div class="text">
    Stuff here... example with absolute and relative positioning
  </div>
</div>
```

styles

```
header { /* background image example */
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
  background-image: url(https://placehold.it/1600x900);
}

.thing img {
  display: block; /* so the image responds to it's parent */
  width: 100%; /*  */
  height: auto; /*  */
}

.thing { /* absolute position example */
  position: relative; /* so it is the new boundery for children that are absolute */
  max-width: 600px;
}

.thing .text {
  position: absolute; /* this will take it out of the flow but let you position it based on parent */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/fvvq4cwq/